# Adding a JScrollPane to the JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I want to add the JScrollPane to the JFrame through this function createDatabaseViewGUI can any give me guide how to do this so i could add this jtable and jscrollpane to the jframe and get it working

```
package schoolclient;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import schoolserver.SchoolInterface;

public class RMIClient extends JFrame {
    SchoolInterface sii = null;
    Object data = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RMIClient rmic = new RMIClient();
        rmic.getSchoolInstacne();
        //rmic.createDatabaseViewGUI();
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
        jFrame.setSize(270, 320);
        jFrame.setContentPane(rmic.createDatabaseViewGUI());
        //Object[] o = rmic.getDatabaseToList();
        //for(Object o : rmic.getDatabaseToList())
        //System.out.println(o);
    }

    public void getSchoolInstacne() {
        try {
            sii = (SchoolInterface) Naming.lookup("SchoolServer"); 
        }
        catch (RemoteException | MalformedURLException | NotBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList getDatabaseToList() {

        ArrayList<Object> data = null;
        try {
            data = sii.getDatabsesName();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    public void createDatabaseViewGUI() {
        Object[] x = new Object[10];
        int i = 0;
        for(Object o : getDatabaseToList())
            x[i++] = o;
        DefaultTableModel defaultTable = new DefaultTableModel();
        defaultTable.addColumn("Databses Names", x);
        JTable jTable = new JTable(defaultTable);
        jTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(250, 350));
        jTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable);
        jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(150);
        int[] selection = jTable.getSelectedRows();
           for (int j = 0; j < selection.length; j++) {
             selection[j] = jTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selection[j]);
        super.add(scrollPane);

        jTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        ListSelectionModel lsm = jTable.getSelectionModel();
        lsm.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel)e.getSource();
                int row = jTable.getSelectedRow();
                data = (Object)jTable.getValueAt(row, 1);
            }
        });
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating two JFrames:  one with `new RMIClient` and one with `new JFrame`.  You are making only one of those JFrames visible.  And your JScrollPane can only belong to one JFrame at a time.  Try changing ‘JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();’ to `JFrame jFrame = rmic;`.

Comment: Your 2 main problems have been stated. Fix those and see what happens.

Comment: i am unable to do the said will you do changes here for me plz

Answer (score 1):

I can guess, you problem here: `rmic.createDatabaseViewGUI()`. This method can not be `void`. It must return value.

```
jFrame.getContentPane(rmic.createDatabaseViewGUI());
```

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane%28java.awt.Container%29):

```
setContentPane(Container contentPane)
Sets the contentPane property.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package schoolclient;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import schoolserver.SchoolInterface;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

public class RMIClient1 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;
    SchoolInterface sii = null;
    String data = null;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RMIClient1 frame = new RMIClient1();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame.setResizable(false);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Couldn't able to load GUI.");
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });     
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public RMIClient1() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 250, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getSchoolInstacne();
        table = new JTable(createView()){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {                
                return false;               
        }
        };
        this.tableValues(table);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    }


    public void getSchoolInstacne() {
        try {
            sii = (SchoolInterface) Naming.lookup("SchoolServer"); 
        }
        catch (RemoteException | MalformedURLException | NotBoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in connecting to Server");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList getDatabaseToList() {

        ArrayList<Object> data = null;
        try {
            data = sii.getDatabsesName();

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in SQL");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in connecting to Server");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    Object[] createArray() {
        Object[] x =  new Object[10];
        int i = 0;
        for(Object o : getDatabaseToList())
            x[i++] = o;

        return x;
    }

    DefaultTableModel createView() {
        DefaultTableModel defaultTable = new DefaultTableModel();
        defaultTable.addColumn("Databses", createArray());

        return defaultTable;
    }

    public void tableValues(JTable table) {
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(150);
        int[] selection = table.getSelectedRows();
           for (int j = 0; j < selection.length; j++) {
             selection[j] = table.convertRowIndexToModel(selection[j]);
           }
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        ListSelectionModel lsm = table.getSelectionModel();
        lsm.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel)e.getSource();
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                data = (String) table.getValueAt(row, 0);
                lsm.setValueIsAdjusting(false);
                SchoolClientGUI frame = new SchoolClientGUI(data);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /*public void setOpen(String data) {
        SchoolClientGUI frame = new SchoolClientGUI(data);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    */
}
```